# Pandas dataframe query with variable column name

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I want to set a variable based on matching between two columns of a dataframe.  Since I have many dataframes and I want to do this operation on all of these, I give the column name as variables fk1 and fk2.  But unfortunately it gives me "KeyError: False"

Previously I was using

```
if not L.query('@Cid1 == id1 and @Cid2 == id2').empty:
    Y[i] = 1
    i += 1
```

and it was working without any problem. But when I use the below code it gives me error

```
if not L.query('@Cid1 == @fk1 and @Cid2 == @fk2').empty:
        Y[i] = 1
        i += 1;
```

Comment: Need to see your `df`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ.  I am loading a csv file with column names  "id1"  "id2"  (in other files  the names cane be "name1" "name2" etc) as the dataframe.  In all cases, the csv will have just two columns with different names.

Comment: I get it. Why not access by index then? `if df[(df.iloc[:, 0] == cid1) & (df.iloc[:, 1] == cid2)].empty: ...`